# Java: Removing the 'print' statement causes a timeout exception when requesting connection(s) from DataSource?

Tags: java, connection-pooling

Can anyone advise on the following general Java issue

Here's some pseudo code (exception handling etc removed) to represent the issue I am having:

```
public void initializeConnection(DataSource dataSource) {

    // Declare collection to hold all connections
    Collection<Connection> pool = new ArrayList<Connection>();

    // Loop through all connections
    int i = 0;
    while(i <= dataSource.getMaxActive()){
       Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
       // do something with connection, then add it to a collection
       pool.add(conn)

       i++;
       // REMOVE THIS PRINT OUT AND CODE THROWS GETCONNECTION TIMEOUT EXCEPTION
       System.out.println( i );

    }

    // Traverse through the collection and close all connections
}
```

The code is quite simple:

1. Loop through all connections in a data source
2. Do something with each connection (more specifically, use it to call a stored procedure to initialize the database state for the connection)
3. Save the connections in a collection so that they can then be closed (if a connection is closed immediately, it will stop us looping through all connections).

The above code works fine. The problem is this: When the print statement is removed, a timeout exception is thrown that no new connection could be retrieved within 30 seconds. 
So there appears to be some sort of threading or timing issue - obviously something is broken, and it only works because of the delay which happens because of the print statement.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke `dataSource.getConnection()` from the same thread multiple times, you will usually get the same connection each time, because it is bound to the thread via a ThreadLocal by the DataSource implementation and it will notice you've already received a connection. I therefore doubt this code actually does what you want.

If that isn't the case, then the code will at least execute the block maxActive + 1 times, which is once too often.